# In Codeception, should I add custom methods to AcceptanceTester or Helper/Acceptance - is there a difference?

Tags: php, automated-tests, codeception

In Codeception, I always get confused by this:
Should I add custom test methods to `_support/AcceptanceTester.php` or `_support/Helper/Acceptance.php`?

Is there a difference?  They both appear to do a similar thing.

Answer (score 1):

Tester class is used by only one suite.
Helper class can be used in multiple suites, but I would use a more descriptive name in that case.